# XAML: How to create a page template

Tags: xaml, uwp

I'm not confortable with windows application development and have a very simple question. I searched, I searched but nothing works.

I would like to have the same following template for each page of my application.

```
<SplitView>
  <SplitView.Pane>...</SplitView.Pane>
  <SplitView.Content>%THE CONTENT OF MY PAGE%</SplitView.Content>
</SplitView>
```

I firstly tried to use UserControl but don't really understand how does it work.
Could you help me please?

My objective : Having the same global menu on each page.

Kind regards,
Ben

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to make a master page is to use the frame control inside the Splitview content like so.

```
 <SplitView>
   <SplitView.Pane>Your menu buttons</SplitView.Pane>
   <SplitView.Content>
      <Frame x:Name="frame" Content="{Binding CurrentFrame, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
   </SplitView.Content>
 </SplitView>
```

Then you wanna data bind the frame to a frameproperty in the ViewModel(if you are using MVVM). and remember to use the INotifyPropertyChanged on the Frame

**ViewModel**

```
public Frame CurrentFrame { get; set;}
```

Then you can bind a command to the button on the menu and navigate to the xaml page you want:

```
    public ICommand GoToDetailsPageCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _goToDetailsPageCommand ?? (_goToDetailsPageCommand = new RelayCommand<Object>((navigate) =>
            {
                CurrentFrame.Navigate(typeof (DetailsPage));
            }));
        }
        set { _goToDetailsPageCommand = value; }
    }
```

Remember databinding on frame and button. Then the frame will switch between the xaml pages, and the master page which contains the split view will act as a global menu on all XAML pages